# node.js - How does Busboy actually work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request-headers, node.js-stream, busboy

I'm a bit confused with [Busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) module. I don't understand where it takes file data to stream as it accepts only request headers as parameter?! Take a look on example from docs:

```
var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
   //...
   // btw file is ReadableStream!
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets the request body piped to it, see [the example](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#examples):

```
req.pipe(busboy);
```

Comment: yeah, now I see, thanks, but internally all request instance will be available then?

Comment: @Kosmetika just the headers and the body are enough for it to do its magic, it doesn't appear to need anything else from the request object.

Comment: I just leave this link here - https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback_1 if somebody will be confused on the streams topic like me. It's  a bit not obvious from the quick look into docs.

Comment: when uploading a 10 gb file from my frontend app (reactjs) to my nodejs server that uses busboy, does the file gets stored anywhere in the nodejs server harddisk as a tmp file?

Comment: @Phantom007 I don't think so, it's a streaming parser.